# error returned when installing webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am working on [this](https://online.reacttraining.com/courses/50507/lectures/760301#/questions/1) tutorial. And I got up to the point where it asks me to install webpack, but when I do using:

```
npm install --save-dev webpack
```

I get the following error:

> webpack-dev-server@2.5.0 requires a peer of webpack@^2.2.0 but none
> was installed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Content in link to tutorial isn't accessible. Maybe remove webpack-dev-server from package.json and/or delete it from node_modules/ and try again? If no go, paste your package.json and node/npm versions.

Comment: it's not even really webpack-dev-server either, I tried to simply install webpack with the install call I used above and it gives me the same error. Node version 6.11 npm 3.11.11

Comment: sorry, i did get webpack-dev-server out of node_modules and then tried to install both - it allowed me to install webpack, but gave the same peer error when reinstalling webpack-dev-server again.

Answer (score 0):

I am also learning from that tutorial. Like the error says, that you have webpack-dev-server@2.5.0 but you are missing the matching version of webpack. If you check the package.json, then you would find the webpack version to be different (maybe it's 3.0.0?).

So, install webpack@^2.2.0 like below:

```
npm install --save-dev webpack@^2.2.0
```

P.S. As I am a beginner, so I may be wrong. Please excuse, if that's the case.